# How to splice sparse matrices randomly for machine learning classification

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, scikits

I'm working on a machine learning assignment that utilizes sparse matrices (in specific, 20 news groups if you are familiar with it). Here is what I have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from random import shuffle

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC

dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
transformer = CountVectorizer().fit(dataset.data)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

def preprocess(data):
    sparse_data = transformer.transform(data)
    training_data = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(sparse_data)
    return training_data


def predict():
    data = preprocess(dataset.data)
    target = dataset.target
    print(data)
    model = LinearSVC().fit(data, target)
    return model
testset=fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test')
data2=preprocess(testset.data)
predicted=predict().predict(data2)
print(np.mean(predicted == testset.target))
```

So, I trained on the entire training data set and then I used my classifier to classify the test data, and this printed out an 88% accuracy. But, I was supposed to train on 80% of the training data and test my classifier on the rest of the training data, and then my code will be checked by my instructor by using the test data. So, I have to randomly partition the training data into 2 sets since the data is in order so training on the first 80% would lead to a bad classifier; in addition, however I randomly partition my training data, I must also correspondingly partition my training target. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To randomly partition the training data into two sets you can use [`sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split). Here is the piece of code your are looking for:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset.data, dataset.target,
                                                    train_size=0.8, random_state=0)

print("Train size: {0}".format(len(X_train)))
print("Test size: {0}".format(len(X_test)))
```

The output is:

```
Train size: 9051
Test size: 2263
```

I hope this will help you.